# Ubuntu phone / Aquaris E5: no ringtones when receiving calls, no sound when receiving messages; no sound on speakers

Tags: sound, ubuntu-touch, phone, speakers

Aquaris E5 HD, Ubuntu Edition; Ubuntu 15.04, OTA-8.5

My phone does not ring / play any sound on speakers. No problems to answer calls, when having notice by vibrating / display notification; I have the phone for some weeks now and at the very beginning sound worked; short after it stopped playing sounds; unmuted and uninstalled pathwind - no difference; sometimes it still plays ringtones - but have no idea under which circumstances; even when it rings for one time, it does not anymore one call later, although I did not make any changes in settings between the two incoming calls; It does not play sounds / ringtones when selecting them in settings (no difference which ringtone I select).

Today I made full reset on phone (by Settings in Menu) - still no sounds.

Does anyone have the same problem?
Does anyone know how to get ringtones / sound / speakers to work?

(Reported bug today: http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1533251 )